# Problems when adding a new column in the evaluate sentence in PBI paginated report

Tags: runtime-error, daxstudio, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a dataset based on a dax code. This is the schema of the query where we use parameters to filter some tables:

```
Declare 

var filtertable1 = .... @param1 ...
...
var filtertablen = .... @paramn ...

Evaluate
sumarizecolumns (
         column1,
         column2
   
         filtertable1
         ...
         filtertablen

         [metric_name]

)
```

When we add a new column : column3 we are getting a generic error. Something like : "..parameter param1 is not declare..". Nothing useful to track the error. However, when we execute the query in dax studio with the same values for the parameters we do have a result.

The strange thing we've noticed is that column2 and column3 seem to be responsible for this error. When we delete one or the other the query is validated, but so far we have not understood why.

Any idea about what we can do to track the error or debug this issu, or what could be happening ?